# Website Not Scrolling Down to Or displaying #proceed Div At the Right Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dAQrE/

At the top of the javascript section you will see code that is suppose to scroll down to the `#proceed` div after the animation when it says:

> > line 1, line 2, line 3, line 4..

proceed div that the page is suppose to scroll to:

```
<div id="proceed">
    <div id="if_one">   <a href="http://websitelinkhere.com/1" class="button_primary agree">If Question 1 = Answer 1</a>
    </div>
    <div id="if_two">   <a href="http://websitelinkhere.com/2" class="button_primary agree">If Question 1 = Answer 2</a>
    </div>
    <div id="if_three"> <a href="http://websitelinkhere.com/3" class="button_primary agree">If Question 1 = Answer 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript that is suppose to scroll to the `#proceed` div after the animation:

```
// assign the correct target
var target = $('#proceed');

$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
}, 200);

// scroll!
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
}, 200, function () {
    target.css({
        'border-color': 'red'
    })
});
```

But right now its displaying the content within the #proceed div before the animation finishes and it doesn't scroll down at all..  How do I fix this?

Comment: All those functions run on page load, right? #proceed isn't even visible at that point. You need to name those functions and call them at the right time.

Comment: @isherwood the script worked fine before, the only issue is scrolling to the #proceed div and getting it to appear correctly but without trying to get it to scroll if I remove the #proceed div and keep the contents within it then it works.. but I need to get this to scroll which is whats causing me the most trouble.. what functions need to be named and called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those functions will get called on document.ready as you have them written. They need to be encapsulated within a function that gets called after "line 1, line 2..." gets displayed.

I have forked your fiddle to do this. Check out your events which I wrapped in a function called `proceed()`, and the changes I made to `verifyAnimation()` to call that function after the last "line x" is displayed.

http://jsfiddle.net/ercFw/

Comment: thanks! I forged the jsfiddle and was able to hide #proceed by adding `display:none` in css and then `display:block` to #proceed on lines 5 and 6 in the new fiddle but how do I get it to wait 2 seconds before displaying the button? Heres the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e6cHn/

Comment: Use `setTimeout` to add a delay.